# Canvas Fabric js Object Handling

Tags: javascript, html, angular, canvas, fabricjs

I am working with fabric js canvas where on left side I have a canvas and on right side I have a table with corresponding canvas data on changing the row in the table image and shapes change on the canvas. Till Here everything is working fine. But the issue is when I select second row and click on a shape it loads the previous row image and shapes. I am new to this, If anybody could help, would be thankful[image]

Comment: Add a snippet of your code that has the issue.

Comment: Can you please show some code that can help me to understand your problem ?

Comment: Hi Please refer to the image above. Here I selected a row where an image and box comes on the canvas but when I try to drag the blue box the previous row data loads